# Import Android AAR with JNI so files

Tags: android, android-ndk, aar

Trying to import AAR as module 'my-java-module' which contains a /jni/x86 folder with two **.so** files. When using the classes from the module, I was getting error saying:

```
W/System.err: Native code library (javamodule) failed to load. 
W/System.err: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.things.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.test.app-a3ZcweiV8k7NhpzM3KSjc==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.test.app-a3ZcweiV8k7NhpzM3KSjc==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libjavamodule.so"
```

So I change module name to 'javamodule' and it loads but now gives no implementation error:

```
E/zygote: No implementation found for void module_function()
```

Question: How do I tell Android to load the /lib/x86 .so files from the AAR module that was imported so that it finds the implementation?

Comment: _"contains a /jni/x86 folder"_ Juding by the error log you seem to be running the app on an ARM device, not x86.

Comment: The imported module was specifically built to run on the Android IoT; so if you're saying it is not including because log is saying ARM, how would I change that? Cause the app is running on the device when not including the module.